# Ordena Frequência Array PHP

Tags: array, php-7

Gostaria de saber como faço para ordena esse Array, colocando os números repetidos no final.

```php
$arr = array(
    5,
    4,
    2,
    3,
    2,
    1
);
sort ($arr);
foreach ($arr as $n => $valor) {
    echo "$valor\n";
}
```

Comment: Dá um exemplo de como quer que fique

Comment: Eu gostaria que ficasse desse jeito: array(1,3,4,5,2,2).

Comment: E se a entrada for `5,4,2,1,3,2,1`?

Comment: Não importaria a quantidade de valores de entrada e sim o retorno dela. Eu pensei em comparar os valores repitidos do array, mas não sei como colocar os valores repitidos no final do array.

Comment: O que eu quero saber é: os não repetidos ficam em que ordem? E se tiver mais de um repetido, qual deve ser a ordem entre eles?

Comment: Agora entendi, desculpa. Todos ficariam em ordem crescente, mas os não repetidos devem vir primeiro no resultado. Por exemplo: array (1,4,2,2,3,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz o seguinte, ordenei o array e depois ordenei a quantidade de repetições, em seguida eu verifiquei se a quantidade era igual a 1, caso contrário ele adiciona no final, através do "for", ele vai adicionando e comparando se é o array atual da repetição:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    5,
    4,
    2,
    3,
    2,
    1
);
sort($arr);
$add = array();

$contagem = array_count_values($arr);
```

//ordena pela quantidade de repetições
    asort($contagem);

```
    $add = array();
foreach($contagem as $valor => $qtde) {
    $current = $valor;
    if($qtde == 1) {
          $add[] = $valor;
    } else {
       //o if aqui é só para adicionar uma vez
        if ($valor === $current) {
           for($i=0; $i < $qtde; $i++) {
              $add[] = $valor;
           }
        }
    }

}
print_r($add);
```

Veja o [exemplo aqui](http://ideone.com/GP6pKo). E aqui com [outros números](http://ideone.com/awIeni)

Answer (score 0):

Por qual motivo você quer eles no final? Talvez o que esteja pensando em fazer, tem alguma outra lógica melhor. Por que basicamente tem duas coisas pra tu fazer com os repetidos: remover, ou contar. Estou pensando que você quer contar, correto?

Talvez seria melhor o array ficar assim:

```
// key é o valor do array original, e o value é a quantidade
$array[1] = 1
$array[2] = 2
$array[3] = 1
$array[4] = 2
```

E posteriormente, se realmente precisar que eles fiquem no final, você ordenaria para o valor ser crescente, com o sort.

Desculpa não dar um exemplo, mas faz tempo que não programo em PHP, somente Javascript. Mas acredito que se mudar a lógica será mais fácil.

Qualquer dúvida durante a criação o código, se estiver precisando de ajuda com a lógica, mande o código que termino pra você. Mas ao menos comece faze-lo!